# Maven error :Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I've never worked with Maven before and I am following the instructions [here.](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html) When I run the command

```
mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war
```

It initially downloaded a whole bunch of dependencies, and in the end it showed,

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
```

I am on ubuntu 13.04.

If there's anything you want me to tell you, let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT**

When I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/`

When I do `mvn -version`

I get,

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.0-26-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Also, I found out [this problem faced by someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620531/maven-pointing-to-jre-instead-of-jdk). But I am not sure how to go about the solution that is specified?

Further edits.

```
kraken@kraken-Inspiron-1545:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  9 10:44 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Jul  4  2013 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-    headless
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 13  2013 jre
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 13  2013 man
```

Comment: Do you have JRE instead of JDK installed?

Comment: I have jdk. When I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` it outputs, /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/

Comment: `Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre` ends with jre, starts with jdk, hmm :P

Comment: If you do `which javac`, what do you get?

Comment: @Zavior I've attached a link to the question, that details it. But I am not sure what is the solution that is prescribed there.

Comment: @Zavior /usr/bin/javac

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Package Compilation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220392/maven-package-compilation-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra)

Comment: @estellezg The question you link focusses on a problem with Maven within Eclipse, this question is different.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Apparently, it requires tools.jar file inside the lib folder of my $JAVA_HOME. I did not have the lib folder, so I reinstalled my jdk using command

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-lib
```

Also, [this link may help some people.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.turbine.maven.user/130257)

Answer (score 180):

I've been facing the same issue with java 8 (ubuntu 16.04), trying to compile using `mvn` command line.

I verified my `$JAVA_HOME`, `java -version` and `mvn -version`. Everything seems to be okay pointing to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

It appears that java-8-openjdk-amd64 is not completly installed by default and only contains the JRE (despite its name "jdk").

Re-installing the JDK did the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then some new files and new folders are added to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` and mvn is able to compile again.

Comment: I guess this is essentially the same thing as the accepted answer - not having JDK you wouldn't have tools.jar either.

Comment: Running `javac -version` should be able to confirm this because it isn't included in the JDK.

Comment: @LittleHelper `javac -version` results in `bash: javac: command not found`

Answer (score 24):

> This is because of running jre rather than jdk, to install jdk follow
> below steps

**Installing java 8 in amazon linux/redhat**

--> `yum search java | grep openjdk`

--> `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64`

--> `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

--> `update-alternatives --config java` #pick java 1.8 and press **1**

--> `update-alternatives --config javac` #pick java 1.8 and press **2**

Thank You

Comment: Yeah, Only JRE was installed in my case as well. We have to install JDK as well.

Comment: On RHEL 7.5 I installed java-1.8.0-openjdk, but this does not include the JAVAC compiler, so based on your information I additionally installed java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 and now I have the JAVAC compiler.  If it is a JRE it should be labeled as such.  This is utter nonsense.  java-1.8.0-openjdk is not a JDK.  Should be called java-1.8.0-openjdk-jre

Answer (score 11):

**Problem statement**  = No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

**Solution**

Please set the **Environment variable** like below to solve the issue

**Variable name** : JAVA_HOME

**Variable Value** :  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

**Variable name** : M2_HOME

**Variable Value** :  C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0

*Moreover*, Add Java and maven path in "**System Variables**" like below:

1. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
2. C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin

Answer (score 7):

For me, it worked like following.
Please look at JAVA_HOME environment variable, whether it is pointing to JRE or JDK.? 
If it pointed to JRE, you will face "Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK" issue. if so change the path to JDK.

Modifying like this, it worked for me.

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Answer (score 7):

I get this error when JAVA_HOME is not properly set.

I have tried this command

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

which gives 3 virtual machines

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
1.8.291.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_291 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_181 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In such case, specific version is required.

This

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

differs from

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**Therefore solution is** to set *~/.bash_profile* with

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0`
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding more details on where to setup.  Main reason would be the JAVA_HOME setup in the environment variable should be pointing to correct JDK location.

> 1. Check System -> Advance System Settings
> 2. Click on Environment variable
> 3. Add variable JAVA_HOME -> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141;"
> 4. Edit "path" -> append %JAVA_HOME%; to the existing text.

Answer (score 5):

i am using `centos` and getting same error when run `mvn` command with goal, `install`. After some googling i have found the solution to run following command.

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Answer (score 4):

Add this configurations in pom.xml

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if /usr/bin has 'javac'. If not you have installed JRE & have to install jdk dev version like "java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64"

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.  I needed to place the JDK before the JRE in PATH in order to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my automatic solution...

This will follow your `javac` executable's symlink (setup by `yum` and/or `alternatives --config java`) backwards to find the `JAVA_HOME`. (Toss this in your in your `/etc/profile`):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed 's:/bin/javac$::')
```

If you wanted a stable path (refreshed on boot) launch something like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed 's:/bin/javac$::')
ln -sfn "${JAVA_HOME}" /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-current
```

I'm kinda shocked the latter still isn't baked into `alternatives`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i fixed my problem

right clik on the project > properties > Java Compiler (select the one you are using)

it was 1.5 for me but i have 1.8 installed. so i changed it to 1.8.. and voilla it worked!.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package on an AWS Linux AMI. The incorrect assumption I made, was that because the file ended in *openjdk* it would be the jdk version. This is not the case.

The [openjdk install page](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) explains everything clearly.

> The java-1.8.0-openjdk package contains just the Java Runtime
>   Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then install the
>   java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel package.

If you've already installed the java-1.8.0-openjdk package, just leave it and the JAVA_HOME value if it's working for the JRE and install the java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel package using `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y`.

Answer (score 1):

In Installed JREs path see if there is an entry pointing to your JDK path or not.
If not, click on Edit button and put the path you configured your `JAVA_HOME` environment:

```
Eclipse Path: Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Mac users who recently updated to MacOS Monterey**

If you've encountered this issue after updating your macOS to Monterey recently, try running this command:

`sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

Afterwards, continue using maven like usual. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I was missing the User variable: JAVA_HOME and the value for the SDK - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1" in my case

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue even though JAVA_HOME was pointing to JDK. It took time to figure out why it was throwing the exception.

The issue was I set JAVA_HOME as admin user on my window machine. You need to add JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to right JDK to your **user profile environment variable settings**.

Answer (score 0):

For solving my issue on Linux don't have a JDK, I just download the JDK and upload to the Linux server, and type:
tar xvf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in **eclipse maven project**, all i did was
right click on the project
**maven** --> **update project**
or just press ALT+ F5

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions doesn't work then try to place java path before maven in path of environment variable. It worked for me.

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1-bin\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below error in Maven project in Eclipse

**Error**: [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

I solved it by following the below solution

**Solution**:
Eclipse->Project->Right click->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Add jdk path(Eg:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45)

**Note**: Earlier Build path in eclipse project was pointing to jre path

And also add jdk path in Environment Variable in Advanced system settings

**Variable Name**: JAVA_HOME

**Variable Value**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

And also make sure in eclipse below pointing is (jdk path-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45 )

**Windows -> Preferneces -> Java -> Installed JRE's**

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your project folder (Maven one), select properties and from the properties window, again select Java Compiler and see what is selected against compiler compliance level and make sure that it is the same version as your jre. In my case I had 1.8 but 1.5 was selected against compiler compliance level. After selecting 1.8 the build was successful without this error.

Answer (score -1):

too many java virtual machines?

place check with command:

> /usr/libexec/java_home -V
> java -version
> mvn -version

[uninstall java click here](https://www.java.com/zh-CN/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html)

Answer (score -1):

I tried all above solutions. However I had to reboot the windows to make settings take effects