# Changing JDK on cluster deployed with ./spark-ec2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, spark-ec2

I have deployed an Amazon EC2 cluster with Spark like so:

```
~/spark-ec2 -k spark -i ~/.ssh/spark.pem -s 2 --region=eu-west-1 --spark-version=1.3.1 launch spark-cluster
```

I copy a file I need first to the master and then from master to HDFS using:

```
ephemeral-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put ~/ANTICOR_2_10000.txt ~/user/root/ANTICOR_2_10000.txt
```

I have a jar I want to run which was compiled with JDK 8 (I am using a lot of Java 8 features) so I copy it over with `scp` and run it with:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://public_dns_with_port --class package.name.to.Main job.jar -f hdfs://public_dns:~/ANTICOR_2_10000.txt
```

The problem is that `spark-ec2` loads the cluster with JDK7 so I am getting the `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

My question is, which are *all* the places where I need to change JDK7 to JDK8?

The steps I am doing thus far on master are:

- Install JDK8 with yum
- Use `sudo alternatives --config java` and change prefered java to java-8
- `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8`

Do I have to do that for all the nodes? Also do I need to change the java path that hadoop uses at `ephemeral-hdfs/conf/hadoop-env.sh` or are there any other spots I missed?

Comment: Was there a way to do it once for all slaves?

Comment: @M-T-A no I did not find one. The most efficient thing that I found was using Terminator (https://launchpad.net/terminator) to ssh in all the slaves and manually change the JDK in all of them at once.

Comment: For future reference, `pssh -i -h /root/spark-ec2/slaves <command>` would definitely run this command on all slaves.

Comment: @M-T-A I see, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Amazon doesn't offer out-of-the-box Java 8 installations, yet: [see available versions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html).

Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588742/java-8-application-on-ec2) on how to install it on running instances?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have been doing for all java installations which are different from versions provided by default installations: -

1. Configure the JAVA_HOME environment variable on each machine/ node: -

   > export JAVA_HOME=/home/ec2-user/softwares/jdk1.7.0_25
2. Modify the default PATH and place the *"java/bin"* directory before the rest of the PATH on all Nodes/ machines.

   > export PATH=/home/ec2-user/softwares/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/:$M2:$SCALA_HOME/bin/:$HIVE_HOME/bin/:$PATH:

And the above needs to be done with the same "OS user" which is used to execute/ own the spark master/ worker process.