# Need help running (hosting) a jar file on Amazon Web Service

Tags: java, jar, vps

Im kinda confused and dont know which one does people use to run jar file and this is the one i want to run https://github.com/Manevolent/EggCrack
Im connected to ec2 instance using ssh now and dont know what to do next...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to:

1. create another EC2 instance;
2. install Java in this new instance;
3. run your jar in it.

However, you can also use another service from AWS, such as [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) or [Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/containers/).

Comment: thanks ive created an EC2 Instance now and dont know how to install java i already connected to the server via ssh

Comment: What is OS of your image?

Comment: My os oh..its Linux

Comment: Ubuntu or CentOS or something else?

Comment: I chose linux not ubuntu or centos

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588742/java-8-application-on-ec2